# Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning -- MERN

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I'm currently working on a MERN app that takes information from a user within input fields and displays them back. I am getting this error after the onSubmit is fired:

```sh
> (node:18820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: 
item validation failed: brand: Path `brand` is required., trailer_type:
Path `trailer_type` is required.
```

Model:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema 
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    brand: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    trailer_type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
```

Router

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Item Model
const Item = require('../../models/Item');

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.post('/', auth, (req, res) => {
    const newItem = new Item({
        brand: req.body.brand,
        trailer_type: req.body.trailer_type,
        date: req.body.date
    });

    newItem.save()
    .then(item => res.json(item));
});
```

I've searched in several different places for someone having a similar issue, but have not had no success with implementing other's solutions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Cabbott, it seems that the data coming from your req.body is undefined when it hits the routes? Can you tell use what console.log(req.body) equals to?

Comment: Tested with Postman. Worked like a charm when I set Content-Type to application/json in the header field. I'm trying to research how i can incorporate that in and see if the req.body will come back defined on the site itself.